# Difference of solution between sequential and parallel programming

Tags: python, python-2.7, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have created a python code that solves a group lasso penalized linear model. For those of you not used to work with these models, the basic idea is that you give as input a dataset (x) and a response variable (y), as well as the value of a parameter (lambda1), varying the value of this parameter changes the solution of the model. So I decided to use the multiprocessing library and solve different models (associated to different parameter values). I created a python file called "model.py" in which there are the following functions:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import division
import functools
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
from cvxpy import *

def lm_gl_preprocessing(x, y, index, lambda1=None):
    lambda_vector = [lambda1]
    m = x.shape[1]
    n = x.shape[0]
    lambda_param = Parameter(sign="positive")
    m = m+1
    index = np.append(0, index)
    x = np.c_[np.ones(n), x]
    group_sizes = []
    beta_var = []
    unique_index = np.unique(index)
    for idx in unique_index:
        group_sizes.append(len(np.where(index == idx)[0]))
        beta_var.append(Variable(len(np.where(index == idx)[0])))
    num_groups = len(group_sizes)
    group_lasso_penalization = 0
    model_prediction = x[:, np.where(index == unique_index[0])[0]] * beta_var[0]
    for i in range(1, num_groups):
        model_prediction += x[:, np.where(index == unique_index[i])[0]] * beta_var[i]
        group_lasso_penalization += sqrt(group_sizes[i]) * norm(beta_var[i], 2)
    lm_penalization = (1.0/n) * sum_squares(y - model_prediction)
    objective = Minimize(lm_penalization + (lambda_param * group_lasso_penalization))
    problem = Problem(objective)
    response = {'problem': problem, 'beta_var': beta_var, 'lambda_param': lambda_param, 'lambda_vector': lambda_vector}
    return response

def solver(problem, beta_var, lambda_param, lambda_vector):
    beta_sol_list = []
    for i in range(len(lambda_vector)):
        lambda_param.value = lambda_vector[i]
        problem.solve(solver=ECOS)
        beta_sol = np.asarray(np.row_stack([b.value for b in beta_var])).flatten()
        beta_sol_list.append(beta_sol)
    return beta_sol_list

def parallel_solver(problem, beta_var, lambda_param, lambda_vector):
    # Divide parameter vector into chunks to be executed in parallel
    num_chunks = mp.cpu_count()
    chunks = np.array_split(lambda_vector, num_chunks)
    # Solve problem in parallel
    pool = mp.Pool(num_chunks)
    global_results = pool.map(functools.partial(solver, problem, beta_var, lambda_param), chunks)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return global_results
```

- The function lm_gl_preprocessing basically defines the model to be solved using the cvxpy module.
- The function solver takes the model details from the previus function, and solves an optimization problem that leads to the final solution of the model.
- The function parallel_solver parallellizes the solver function using multiprocessing.

If, in the python console, I start runnig the parallel solver, it gives a solution. This solution is different than the one provided by the sequential solver. 
If I restart the python console and start runnig the sequential solver, and then I run the parallel solver, the parallel solver gives the same solution as the sequential solver. I will show:

```
from __future__ import division
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import numpy as np
import model as t

boston = load_boston()
x = boston.data
y = boston.target
index = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5])

lambda1 = 1e-3

r1 = t.lm_gl_preprocessing(x=x, y=y, index=index, lambda1=lambda1)
s_parallel_1 = t.parallel_solver(problem=r1['problem'], beta_var=r1['beta_var'], lambda_param=r1['lambda_param'], lambda_vector=r1['lambda_vector'])
print(s_parallel_1)
[[array([  4.61648376e+01,  -1.22394832e-04,   0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00,   1.37065733e-04,   1.51910696e-03,
       0.00000000e+00,   1.51910696e-03,   0.00000000e+00,
       7.00079603e-03,   1.52776114e-03,  -8.67357376e-01,
       7.16429750e-03,  -8.67357376e-01])], [], [], []]
s_1 = t.solver(problem=r1['problem'], beta_var=r1['beta_var'], lambda_param=r1['lambda_param'], lambda_vector=r1['lambda_vector'])
print(s_1)
[array([  3.62813738e+01,  -1.06995338e-01,   4.64210526e-02,
      1.97112192e-02,   2.68475527e+00,  -1.75142155e+01,
      3.80741843e+00,   5.14842823e-04,  -1.47105323e+00,
      3.04949407e-01,  -1.23508259e-02,  -9.50143293e-01,
      9.40708993e-03,  -5.25758097e-01])]
#####################################################
r1 = t.lm_gl_preprocessing(x=x, y=y, index=index, lambda1=lambda1)
s_1 = t.solver(problem=r1['problem'], beta_var=r1['beta_var'], lambda_param=r1['lambda_param'], lambda_vector=r1['lambda_vector'])
print(s_1)
[array([  3.62813738e+01,  -1.06995338e-01,   4.64210526e-02,
      1.97112192e-02,   2.68475527e+00,  -1.75142155e+01,
      3.80741843e+00,   5.14842823e-04,  -1.47105323e+00,
      3.04949407e-01,  -1.23508259e-02,  -9.50143293e-01,
      9.40708993e-03,  -5.25758097e-01])]
s_parallel_1 = t.parallel_solver(problem=r1['problem'], beta_var=r1['beta_var'], lambda_param=r1['lambda_param'], lambda_vector=r1['lambda_vector'])
print(s_parallel_1)
[[array([  3.62813738e+01,  -1.06995338e-01,   4.64210526e-02,
       1.97112192e-02,   2.68475527e+00,  -1.75142155e+01,
       3.80741843e+00,   5.14842823e-04,  -1.47105323e+00,
       3.04949407e-01,  -1.23508259e-02,  -9.50143293e-01,
       9.40708993e-03,  -5.25758097e-01])], [], [], []]
```

PS: I know that in this example I am using parallel programming just to solve one model with one possible parameter value, but this is just a little example designed to show the difference of solutions provided by sequential and parallel programming here. I would thank any hint since I am completely lost here.

Comment: From the output of `parallel_solver` I see that all the processes, except one, are returning empty lists. So I guess only one process is actually performing the task.

It is difficult to answer without knowing the model code. My guess is that when you call `solver`, some of the parameters (e.g., `problem`) are modified. So, if you call `parallel_solver` after `solver`, you are passing modified parameters, thus the different result.

Comment: Yes @Amedeo, in this case I am executing just a task with one parameter value, so the output from the parallel version is just one process. Regarding your guess, it was a good one but I tried executing the preprocessing function+the solver, and then again preprocessing+parallel solver (so the inputs such as problem that could have been changed by solver, are once again the same for parallel solver) and I found the same results as those posted here.

Comment: See my answer below. I reproduced your test and got the right result. Try my code and check the result. If it is different, my only guess is that you have some outdated library and maybe an update can solve the problem. As an example, to run your code I had to downgrade cvxpy to v0.4. The last version (1.0) has a different parameter for "Parameter()" (`nonneg=True` instead of `sign="positive"`).

Comment: I have just run your code and I get different solutions just like in my post... I will upgrade the modules and check if the error persist. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @Amedeo im just curious, are you using python on linux or windows? I am trying to upgrade cvxpy in miniconda in a windows machine but all what It shows is 0.4 version

Comment: I am running it on Linux. I have updated my post with the environment info. I will test it also on Windows to double check.

Comment: Using Windows+Anaconda+cvxpy0.4  I also see the wrong output.  In Anaconda I can update to cvxpy1.0, but this requires some changes to the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I execute your code I get the same result in all the cases. This is the code that I am running (I merged the 2 files):

```
from __future__ import division
import functools
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
from cvxpy import *
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston

def lm_gl_preprocessing(x, y, index, lambda1=None):
    lambda_vector = [lambda1]
    m = x.shape[1]
    n = x.shape[0]
    lambda_param = Parameter(sign="positive")
    m = m+1
    index = np.append(0, index)
    x = np.c_[np.ones(n), x]
    group_sizes = []
    beta_var = []
    unique_index = np.unique(index)
    for idx in unique_index:
        group_sizes.append(len(np.where(index == idx)[0]))
        beta_var.append(Variable(len(np.where(index == idx)[0])))
    num_groups = len(group_sizes)
    group_lasso_penalization = 0
    model_prediction = x[:, np.where(index == unique_index[0])[0]] * beta_var[0]
    for i in range(1, num_groups):
        model_prediction += x[:, np.where(index == unique_index[i])[0]] * beta_var[i]
        group_lasso_penalization += sqrt(group_sizes[i]) * norm(beta_var[i], 2)
    lm_penalization = (1.0/n) * sum_squares(y - model_prediction)
    objective = Minimize(lm_penalization + (lambda_param * group_lasso_penalization))
    problem = Problem(objective)
    response = {'problem': problem, 'beta_var': beta_var, 'lambda_param': lambda_param, 'lambda_vector': lambda_vector}
    return response

def solver(problem, beta_var, lambda_param, lambda_vector):
    beta_sol_list = []
    for i in range(len(lambda_vector)):
        lambda_param.value = lambda_vector[i]
        problem.solve(solver=ECOS)
        beta_sol = np.asarray(np.row_stack([b.value for b in beta_var])).flatten()
        beta_sol_list.append(beta_sol)
    return beta_sol_list

def parallel_solver(problem, beta_var, lambda_param, lambda_vector):
    # Divide parameter vector into chunks to be executed in parallel
    num_chunks = mp.cpu_count()
    chunks = np.array_split(lambda_vector, num_chunks)
    # Solve problem in parallel
    pool = mp.Pool(num_chunks)
    global_results = pool.map(functools.partial(solver, problem, beta_var, lambda_param), chunks)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return global_results

if __name__ == "__main__":
     boston = load_boston()
     x = boston.data
     y = boston.target
     index = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5])

     lambda1 = 1e-3

     r1 = lm_gl_preprocessing(x=x, y=y, index=index, lambda1=lambda1)
     s_parallel_1 = parallel_solver(problem=r1['problem'], beta_var=r1['beta_var'], lambda_param=r1['lambda_param'], lambda_vector=r1['lambda_vector'])
     print(s_parallel_1)
     r1 = lm_gl_preprocessing(x=x, y=y, index=index, lambda1=lambda1)
     s_1 = solver(problem=r1['problem'], beta_var=r1['beta_var'], lambda_param=r1['lambda_param'], lambda_vector=r1['lambda_vector'])
     print(s_1)
     print ("#####################################################")
     r1 = lm_gl_preprocessing(x=x, y=y, index=index, lambda1=lambda1)
     s_1 = solver(problem=r1['problem'], beta_var=r1['beta_var'], lambda_param=r1['lambda_param'], lambda_vector=r1['lambda_vector'])
     print(s_1)
     r1 = lm_gl_preprocessing(x=x, y=y, index=index, lambda1=lambda1)
     s_parallel_1 = parallel_solver(problem=r1['problem'], beta_var=r1['beta_var'], lambda_param=r1['lambda_param'], lambda_vector=r1['lambda_vector'])
     print(s_parallel_1)
```

and output:

```
[[array([ 3.62813738e+01, -1.06995338e-01,  4.64210526e-02,  1.97112192e-02,
        2.68475527e+00, -1.75142155e+01,  3.80741843e+00,  5.14842823e-04,
       -1.47105323e+00,  3.04949407e-01, -1.23508259e-02, -9.50143293e-01,
        9.40708993e-03, -5.25758097e-01])], [], [], []]
[array([ 3.62813738e+01, -1.06995338e-01,  4.64210526e-02,  1.97112192e-02,
        2.68475527e+00, -1.75142155e+01,  3.80741843e+00,  5.14842823e-04,
       -1.47105323e+00,  3.04949407e-01, -1.23508259e-02, -9.50143293e-01,
        9.40708993e-03, -5.25758097e-01])]
#####################################################
[array([ 3.62813738e+01, -1.06995338e-01,  4.64210526e-02,  1.97112192e-02,
        2.68475527e+00, -1.75142155e+01,  3.80741843e+00,  5.14842823e-04,
       -1.47105323e+00,  3.04949407e-01, -1.23508259e-02, -9.50143293e-01,
        9.40708993e-03, -5.25758097e-01])]
[[array([ 3.62813738e+01, -1.06995338e-01,  4.64210526e-02,  1.97112192e-02,
        2.68475527e+00, -1.75142155e+01,  3.80741843e+00,  5.14842823e-04,
       -1.47105323e+00,  3.04949407e-01, -1.23508259e-02, -9.50143293e-01,
        9.40708993e-03, -5.25758097e-01])], [], [], []]
```

As you can see, I have the same number of CPUs (4).

My environment is Python2.7 on Linux and these are the versions of the relevant packages:

```
>>> import sklearn
>>> sklearn.__version__
'0.19.2'
>>> import scipy
>>> scipy.__version__
'1.1.0'
>>> import numpy 
>>> numpy.__version__
'1.15.2'
>>> import cvxpy
>>> cvxpy.__version__
'0.4.0'
>>> import multiprocessing
>>> multiprocessing.__version__
'0.70a1'
```